# Can't access Windows share by hostname

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, windows-vista, file-sharing

I have an interesting problem.  One of my clients can't access our file server by hostname.  If I open explorer and type `\\Server1` all I see is a single folder, but if I type it's IP `\\10.10.10.10`, I can see all the shares on the machine.  I can see that the DNS is resolving correctly. If I `ping Server1` it will resolve to `10.10.10.10`.  What would cause this?

- The client is running Windows Vista.
- The server is running Windows Server 2003.
- He has permissions for all the shares on the server.
- This is part of an Active Directory domain.

Comment: Do you have multiple DNS records for the same server, like an A record and a CNAME record?

Comment: Furthermore, do you have a WINS server on the network and if so, are you sure the records are correct

Comment: Yes I have a WINS server, it is configured correctly. My DNS is as well.  This is only happening to the one person.  There are over 50 other people that can connect just fine.

Comment: On that Vista machine, do you have 'File and Print Sharing' enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can he see the missing shared folders by going to `\\server.domain.TLD`? For example, in my home network, I'd access one of my machines via its FQDN by typing `\\axon.wesleydomain.internal`

Try adding the DNS domain suffix in the TCP/IP advanced properties of the troubled computer. That option should be set via DHCP option 015 as a best practice.

Furthermore, have you checked the `lmhosts` file to make sure nothing funny has been added to it?

Comment: Yes, he can browse to it's FQDN.  Also, he is not using an lmhosts file.

Comment: So he can see all shares if he connects via FQDN but not if he simply uses the netbios name? I'd simply add the FQDN to each PC's DNS suffix list via DHCP option 015. That is a best practice anyway. Or if you don't want to make that sweeping change, then just add the FQDN into that individual PC's TCP/IP properties.

Comment: Using the FQDN is a good diagnostic step, but it doesn't fix the real problem. It is important to fix the real issue because some software (QuickBooks 2012) will choke on drives mapped with an FQDN.